# Installing Hubot on Hipchat (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, bots

Hello I am trying to install Hubot on a Ubuntu machine but can't get it to run.

I'm using version 2.1.3 of Hubot and following this documentation for hipchat

https://github.com/hipchat/hubot-hipchat

Once I update the `package.json` file on Hubots root and upload the `hipchat.coffee` in `./src` and run the command. it says `cannot find module 'hubot'`

I have no idea where this error is coming from and any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

It's now giving me errors regarding not being able to run the hipchat coffee script itself.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'robot'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hubot/src/hipchat.coffee:7:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hubot/src/hipchat.coffee:234:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..coffee (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:21:21)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:5:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:105:4)
```

This is the file being referred

https://github.com/hipchat/hubot-hipchat/blob/master/src/hipchat.coffee

I havent modified a single line of code. Just executing instructions mentioned in hipchats readme and hubots readme

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with hubot-hipchat 1.0.4 and older versions of Hubot. I resolved this issue by setting the hubot version in packages.json to grab the latest with:

```
"hubot": ">=1.0.3"
```